# get associated values of all hidden elements

Tags: jquery

how do I get the associated values of a hidden input type.

I have this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var input = $("<input>", { type: "hidden", value: "Darren Criss" });
 $('#tokens').append($(input));
 });
```

but this is a specific value.

html :

```
<input id="1" class="stores" type="hidden" value="Darren Criss" taxonomies_count="9"    
name="1" disabled="disabled"></input>

<input id="2" class="stores" type="hidden" value="Ann Arbor T-shirt Company" 
taxonomies_count="46" name="2" disabled="disabled"></input>

<input id="3" class="stores" type="hidden" value="StarKid Productions Store" 
taxonomies_count="22" name="3" disabled="disabled"></input>

<input id="4" class="stores" type="hidden" value="Joe Moses One Man Showses" 
taxonomies_count="3" name="4" disabled="disabled"></input> ....
```

when I select a store value in my input I want that value to be submitted. multiple stores can be selected like tokens

Comment: Define  _"associated values"_.

Comment: What do you mean by "associated values"? Where would they even come from? All you've shown us is a single snippet of code that sets a specific value.

Comment: i have value=1 value=2 value=3, I want these values to be available to append not just value: "Darren Criss"

Comment: You have multiple values for one input field? Or are you asking to get all the values from all hidden input fields?

Comment: You can have only one single value by hidden input, but you can have several hidden inputs with the same name : `name="myinput[]"`

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple values for one input?? If you could supply more code I think it would help us understand more of what you want?

Comment: Please, edit your question, show us the relevant HTML and show us the desired output from the jQuery you're asking us to help with.

Comment: question is edited sorry